# websocket working but not updating my html table

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, phpwebsocket

I have 2 files. index.php is my table that is generated in php from database, which works fine. Then edit page that updates to database, also working fine. both files have javascript for websocket which work fine. however after edit form is submitted i want to update index.php table using websocket but it does not update table. Below are my two files

**index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Names</title>
        <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body><br>

    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover mytables" id="dataTables-example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
            <?php
                if(!empty($table_data)){
                    foreach($table_data as $key=> $value){
                        $name = $value['name'];
            ?>
            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                    }
                }
            ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //create a new WebSocket object.

        var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9000/server.php";   
        websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 

        // connection is open 
        websocket.onopen = function(ev) { 
            console.log('socket is open');
        }
        // Message received from server
        websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
            $('#dataTables-example').load ('index.php', '#dataTables-example');

        };

        websocket.onerror   = function(ev){ 
            console.log('socket is error');
        }; 
        websocket.onclose   = function(ev){ 
            console.log('socket is closed');
        }; 


    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**edit.php:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>names</title>
        <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body><br>

    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form" id="search" name="search" action="edit.php" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <center><button class="btn  btn-success btn-md" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Save</button></center>

    </form>

    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#submit').click(function(){
            send_message();
        });

        //create a new WebSocket object.
        var wsUri = "ws://localhost:9000/server.php";   
        websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri); 

    });

    function send_message(){
        websocket.send('update tables');
        console.log('sending to message to index'); 
    }


    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: did you get any errors?

Comment: no errors and i can see the sever return on index.php console log which is triggered by edit.php.. so the two files communicate well